# How to install the RED Robot Framework Editor plug-in manually into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, robotframework

Our corporate firewall is not allowing traffic directly towards SourceForge so we were supplied the plug-in JAR file through a fileshare. We have used the following download [link](http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/red-robot-editor/repository/0.8.13/plugins/org.robotframework.ide.eclipse.main.plugin_0.8.13.201907181006.jar).

We found several instructions to install plug-ins manually but we were not able to. It looks like this JAR file is not suitable for manual installation? Or what are the steps we need to take?

**Update 19-09-2019**
The following log is generated. No signs of processing of the dropins folder.

```
eclipse.buildId=4.12.0.I20190605-1800
java.version=1.8.0_191
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -clean -console -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.core 1 0 2019-09-19 15:15:47.713
!MESSAGE Using Apache MINA sshd as ssh client.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2019-09-19 15:15:57.883
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\myusername'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Comment: That does look like a single plug-in - copy it to the 'dropins' directory in the Eclipse install

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I copied the jar-file to this dropins subfolder in the Eclipse program folder, but to no avail. I don't see the plugin functions popping up. How to diagnose? https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any messages.

Comment: Added the log file to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Eclipse., Help -> Install New Software -> Add
2. Give "RED" in name and paste the link in the location
3. "https://sourceforge.net/projects/red-robot-editor/files/repository/0.9.1/"
4. Click Add
5. Select Check Box and Click Next
6. Then Click Finish